# how to convert the perl hash string reference to perl hash reference

Tags: perl, sockets, hash, reference, dereference

```
 HASH(0x991f0dc)
```

so the above hash reference is stored as string in scalar variable,if we
dereference it with "%" in the Perl program it throws error,

`Can't use string ("HASH(0x991f0dc)
") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at tcpclient1.pl line 49, <GEN0> line 1`

this above is throws from Perl program,i request solution,to convert back the hash string reference to Perl hash reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You can't convert this back**.

The `HASH(0x991f0dc)` is not a hash reference. It is the string representation of a variable that contains a reference to a hash at that address. The error message you describe when you deref it points to that you have something similar to this:

```
my $foo = 'HASH(0x991f0dc)';
print %$foo;
```

Now that won't work, because the actual data structure is not there.

It looks like you got this over a socket that you read from through the `GEN0` filehandle. Whoever sends you that data structure is doing something wrong.

They need to *serialize* the data, and then you need to *deserialize* it back. A good way to do that is [JSON](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/JSON). But you could also use [Storable](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/Storable), or [Sereal](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/Sereal).